# how to enter string as value in inputs requested in command prompt in java without scanner

Tags: java, cmd, automation, automated-tests, java-io

I am new to handling cmd.exe in java. I am trying to automate one application which is run by CLI.

I want to pass string values when the command prompt has asked for input from user. In this case the question asked is **enter locale:**

I want to pass **en-us** as a string in the question asked in the command prompt.

I don't wanna use scanner class since it will require human intervention.

This is my code :

```
public class run {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        String[] commands = {"cd C:\\Users\\Aniket Shikhare\\Documents\\contentstack-cli-new","csdx cm:export --auth-token","en-us"};

        for(String command : commands) {

            execute(command);
        }

    }


    public static void execute(String command) throws InterruptedException, IOException {
        ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe","/c",command);
        Process process = builder.inheritIO().start();
        process.waitFor();

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
        
    }
}
```

My code is not able to enter **en-us**  when the question is prompted. Can anyone help me how to enter this in the prompt ?

Below image is the output of my code.
[cmd prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vm3GJ.png)

Comment: `process.getOutputStream().write("en-us".getBytes())`

Comment: @Abra this should be and Answer! :)